# .bak file not visible for restoration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, restore

There is a database on a server of which I would like a copy on my local machine for testing purposes, so I created a backup in the default disk location (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup`). The backup dialog says it completes successfully, but when I go to restore the .bak, it's not visible to the file selection dialog (significant file names blurred, obviously).

[image]

There are other viable backups in the same location, but the one I supposedly created does not appear. When attempting to recreate the backup, the one I created appears as a selectable option, while the others in the folder do not.

[image]

What is the issue here? I don't think it's a permissions problem because I'm able to access the other backups in the same folder.

Edit: The backup was on the server which has a similar file structure to my machine. I remoted in to the server and copied the file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What happens if you try changing the file type selection to "All Files (*)"

Comment: Just to confirm: the DB you're backing up is on your local machine, and when you restore it (under a different name), the restored DB will also be on your local machine - correct?

Comment: Have you tried backing up to a non-default folder (after making sure the DB Engine user account has rights to that folder)?

Comment: Program Files vs. Program Files (x86) folder?

Answer (score 1):

I've made the mistake before of missing out or mistyping the *.bak* file extension during backup and then it fails to display file when trying to locate for restore.

Answer (score 1):

You did not save the files where you think you did.

In the first image there are 9 folders below 'Microsoft SQL Server' and above 'MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER'  in the second screen shot there are only 5.

This is possibly an issues with your local machine VS a seperate server. Assuming the address you are following are identical (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup`) the only solution remaining is that the C drives are on different machines.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server keeps track of the actual location it wrote the backup file to.  Review this T-SQL to get the information you need.

```
SELECT  TOP 10  
            [a].[server_name],
            [a].[database_name],
            [a].[backup_finish_date],
            [a].[backup_size],
            CASE [a].[type]
                WHEN 'D' THEN 'Full'
                WHEN 'I' THEN 'Differential'
                WHEN 'L' THEN 'Transaction Log'
                ELSE [a].[type]
            END AS [BackupType],
            [b].[physical_device_name]
FROM        [msdb].[dbo].[backupset] AS [a]
JOIN        [msdb].[dbo].[backupmediafamily] AS [b] ON [a].[media_set_id] = [b].[media_set_id]
WHERE       [a].[database_name] = ''
ORDER BY    [a].[backup_finish_date] DESC
```

If you are unable to find the file in the location SQL Server specifies, that indicates one of the following scenarios:

1. You do not have permission on the disk to view the file
2. The file has been moved / deleted by a user or process

Source of T-SQL: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2960/sql-server-backup-paths-and-file-management/

Answer (score 0):

It is not permission related situation. I have seen this situation in so many forums where user do not find the .bak file for restoring.

In that case, you can take a backup of the database at any location on the local machine and, copy the .bak file to the backup folder of the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was as simple as moving the .bak files to the path for that SQL instance. I.E., C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA You will know you are at the correct place if you can see the master/model/msdb databases.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).